# GCP: How can I create multiple subnets with the same address range in one VPC?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops, system-administration

I am not an expert in the field of GCP, so I immediately want to apologize for the stupid questions.

I read the documentation, found the necessary information, but it does not completely answer my questions.

Can you help me?

VPC contains a subnet from each region.
There can be several subnets in one VPC.
Subnets use a set of predefined ranges of IP addresses.
It turns out that each subnet can have the same range of IP addresses? It's right ?

I was confused by what I read in the GCP documentation:

> Having new subnets automatically created as new regions become
>   available could overlap with IP addresses used by manually created
>   subnets or static routes, or could interfere with your overall network
>   planning.
>
> Because the subnets of every auto mode network use the same predefined
>   range of IP addresses, you cannot connect auto mode networks to one
>   another.
>
> Primary and secondary ranges for subnets cannot overlap with any
>   allocated range, any primary or secondary range of another subnet in
>   the same network, or any IP ranges of subnets in peered networks.

Based on the documentation, I can conclude that:

There are 2 ways to create a subnet:

- creating a subnet in automatic mode.*
- creating a network in user mode.*

It turns out each subnet uses its own range of addresses inside. I can create several subnets with the same range, but I can’t connect between them - is it only when I use the creation of a subnet in automatic mode, or does this also apply to user mode? Or am I wrong ?

---

**UPDATED:**

As far as I understood from the answers in the comment:

*that within one VPC each subnet should be unique and not overlapping.*

But the fact is that I need to have several subnets with the same range of addresses within one VPC.

Can you tell me something how to solve this situation? 
Maybe there are some solutions?

Comment: Limit your posts to one question. Post multiple questions if necessary.

Comment: @JohnHanley ok, thanks. I will do several questions

Answer (score 3):

> VPC contains a subnet from each region. There can be several subnets
>   in one VPC. Subnets use a set of predefined ranges of IP addresses. It
>   turns out that each subnet can have the same range of IP addresses?
>   It's right ?

No, within one VPC, each subnet must be unique and non-overlapping. What Google is trying to explain to you is: If you create your own addresses, those addresses might conflict with addresses that Google creates. This means that Google is not checking if the address is already being used.

> My question is this: Can I increase the quotas for all the resources
>   that are provided on the quota page in the console?

That depends on your definition. You can request quota increases. Be prepared to justify the quota increase and have the "credit" qualification to use and pay for those resources.

Comment: Thanks. But what about Firewall rules ?

Comment: Create several questions. For firewall rules your question is too broad and not well defined.

Comment: I created my new question about Firewall rules: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59143293/gcp-firewall-rules-limits/59143536?noredirect=1#comment104513926_59143536

Comment: Thanks for the tip about VPC. How should I be in this situation? Do you have any ideas on this?

Comment: In what situation? If you mean overlapping or duplicate subnets, re-read the first part of my answer. You manually created a subnet that overlaps a default subnet (as in predefined) CIDR.

Comment: Yes I understand. But if I need an VPC network to contain the same range of addresses. I can not achieve this? Maybe there are some workarounds to solve this problem?

Comment: This is very basic networking. Did you take the time to watch the video that I recommended? There are a lot more so that you learn the fundamentals. You are stating that you want X but you don't have any idea why you want X. Once you understand the fundamentals, you won't worry about X because you will understand how things work and how they are configured. Start at the beginning, not at the end.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did not see the message about the video you are talking about. Could you share the link to the video? I will definitely study it thoroughly. Thanks a lot

Comment: The link is on your other question under Kolban's answer.

Comment: I watched your video about Firewall rules. Thanks, now it’s become clearer.
But I would like to return to the issue related to the VPC and subnets.

Comment: You wrote that within one VPC each subnet should be unique and not overlapping.
But the fact is that I need to have several subnets with the same range of addresses within one VPC.
Can you tell me something how to solve this situation? Maybe there are some solutions?

Comment: There is no solution to your question as it contradicts with the purpose of VPC networks. I would suggest updating your question and describing what kind of resources you want to use, why would they use subnets with same IP ranges and so on. Then someone might come up with a workaround for you.

Comment: You cannot have overlapping subnets or duplicate address ranges. Think about it. How would routing work? How would the network know which computer to send the packet to if two computers have the same IP address? On your home network cofigure two computers with the same IP address and watch what happens.